# Код не реагирует на условия

Tags: javascript

```
var getDayOfWeek = function (first, num) {
  var str = '';

  if (first === 'понедельник' && num % 7 === 1) {
      str = first;
  } else if (first === 'вторник' && num % 7 === 1) {
      str = first;
  } else if (first === 'среда' && num % 7 === 1) {
      str = first;
  } else if (first === 'четверг' && num % 7 === 1) {
      str = first;
  } else if (first === 'пятница' && num % 7 === 1) {
      str = first;
  } else if (first === 'суббота' && num % 7 === 1) {
      str = first;
  } else {
      str = first;
  }
  return str;
}

getDayOfWeek('среда', 10);
```

В условиях четко прописано, что если первый параметр равен понедельнику **И** остаток от деления на 7 равен 1, в таком случае строка принимает значение первого параметра. А получается так, что строка в любом случае принимает значение первого параметра

Comment: А в чем вопрос то? если любом случае принимает, значит и по понедельникам тоже...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
} else {
  str = first;
}
```

Не торопитесь. Подумайте.